# error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'files'

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, angular-test

I have recently installed Jest in my Angular application. No code has been written so far. I have uninstalled Jasmin and karma from my app.

Whenever I run the jest test, I am getting, "error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'files'."

Note that I have not done any changes in the spec file that I am testing i.e., app.component.spec.ts after uninstalling Jasmin and karma

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "jest-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "jest-app": "file:",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^13.1.1",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setup.jest.ts"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/dist/"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsconfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.html$"
      }
    }
  }
}
```